# Show validation accuracy while training the Keras CAPTCHA OCR model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on project with [Keras Captcha OCR model](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/). This model is about text Captcha recognition with CTC encoded output, apart form combining CNN and RNN.

I am trying to see the accuracy number from training output. How can I get the number of accuracy and validation accuracy?

Here is the training code form keras model:

```
epochs = 100
early_stopping_patience = 10
# Add early stopping
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss", patience=early_stopping_patience, restore_best_weights=True
)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
)
```

And this is the training output:

```
Epoch 1/100
59/59 [==============================] - 3s 53ms/step - loss: 21.5722 - val_loss: 16.3351
Epoch 2/100
59/59 [==============================] - 2s 27ms/step - loss: 16.3335 - val_loss: 16.3062
Epoch 3/100
59/59 [==============================] - 2s 27ms/step - loss: 16.3360 - val_loss: 16.3116
Epoch 4/100
59/59 [==============================] - 2s 27ms/step - loss: 16.3318 - val_loss: 16.3167
Epoch 5/100
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `model.fit` just specify the metric you want to compute during training, in this case accuracy:

```
model.compile(optimizer= your_optimizer, loss= your_loss, metrics=['acc'])
```

Link to the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/).